# How to redirect to specific accordian kind tab

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-accordion

Below is the left tabs navigation stuff.

```
            <div class="accordianDiv">
                <ul>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">tab 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab2">document tab 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab3">tab 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

It works fine.

When i do redirect from other page to this page then, it did not work.

i do redirect using- `window.location`.

Please help me how i should allow to default select as tab3 when redirect from other specific page.

NOTE: current manual click navigation work thorugh below code;

```
//On Click Event
$("ul.tabs li").click(function () {
    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
    return false;
});
```

Comment: your markup is wrong, remove `</span>` from `<a href="#tab1"></span>tab 1</a></li>`

Comment: removed. But how to select default tab when redirect from other page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : after page load, remove `active` class from first `li` and add class to `li` having `<a href="#tab3">`

```
$(function(){
  //remove active tab
  $('.accordianDiv ul li.active').removeClass('active');
  //select active tab
  $('.accordianDiv ul li a[href="#tab3"]').parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Applied this but, it makes two active (highlighted) tabs . One id for default tab1 and other is tab3. also, not showing tab3 DIV, it remains on tab1 DIV  only. Please guide.

Comment: which accordian plugin you are using?

Comment: can we trigger click event of href using jquery direclty so, i can fire click vent based on tab1/2/3  ?and it should work.

Comment: Edited question with some additional details. just reviewed accordian js (it was online on cline'ts machine). apologies for confusion.

Comment: posted onclick is present in your code or inside plugin? try with `$('.accordianDiv ul li a[href="#tab3"]').parent().click();`

Comment: if i could fire `$("ul.tabs li").click(` event for `href[#tab3`]. then, it would work.

Answer (score 0):

append the #tab at the of your url and open a particular section after the accordion gets initialized:

```
$(function(){
      $("#accordianDiv").accordion();
      if (location.hash != '') {
            // subtract 1 because activate uses zero based indexes 
            var section = parseInt(location.hash.replace('#tab',''))-1; 
            $('#accordianDiv').accordion("activate",section);
      }
});
```

then redirect with

```
window.location.href = "http://domain.com/page#tab1"
```